# How to find documents which are causing mapping conflict in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-forwarder, sense

I have following Logstash filter:

```
...
if [type] == "binarysize" {
            if ([file] =~ /svn/) {
                    drop {} }
            grok {
                    match => {
                            "file" => "\A/home/data/binaries_size_stats/%{WORD:branch}/%{WORD:binary}/%{WORD:architecture}/%{WORD}"
                    }
            }
            grok {
                    match => {
                            "message" => "\A%{INT:commit_number},%{INT:binary_size},%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:date_and_time_of_commit}"
                    }
            }
           date {
                     match =>  ["date_and_time_of_commit", "ISO8601"]
                    #timezone => "CET"
           }
   }
...
```

I started it, pushed some data into Elasticsearch, did some plots in Kibana and left everything working nicely for the weekend.

When I returned, my plots are not updated with new data and I receive constant "**14 Courier Fetch: 15 of 2465 shards failed.**" message no matter how much I reload page in browser.

After reloading field list I found that I have one conflict in "binary_size" field. I was plotting data based on this field, so my guess is that something weird happened over weekend with new documents pushed to Elasticsearch by Logstash.

My question is: "**How can I find those documents with conflicting fields?**". Or what should I do alternatively to be able to plot fresh data again.

Comment: If you're running elasticsearch v1, the plugin that helps with migrations to v2 will show them.  Otherwise, I think you have to pull the mappings and do some 'diff'ing.